# Date is sorting first by day and then month

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to sort two columns to dates.

It is sorting first by day and then month.

01/06/22
02/06/22
03/06/22
30/05/2022

```vb
Last_row = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
With Sheets("Raw Data")
    .Range("A2:A" & Last_row).Cells.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
    .Range("C2:C" & Last_row).Cells.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
    .Range("A1:AT" & Last_row).Sort Key1:=.Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=.Range("H1"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Comment: Looks like those dates are stored as text in the cell instead of values.

Comment: First check your values in cells. If they are text you need to convert them to date values first. Use `=CELL("format",A1)`. If you got result `G` then they are not dates. If you got result `D4` then they are dates.

Comment: Look at how the data was entered into those cells in the first place. Correct the problem there first.

Comment: Thanks all. I thought I did correct the format/celll data type with the Cells.NumberFormat = 'd/m/yyyy' code. I've also used dd/mm/yyyy that didn't fix it. Yes the dates are stored as text and I thought the code on the columns would change that format. I want to avoid applying a formula cell by cell in my ranges. Or is it unavoidable and I have to apply a conversion to number/date cell by cell?

Comment: If your data is text, Excel will treat it as text. Formatting a cell doesn't change the content of a cell, only it's representation. If data is date, Excel will sort it as date, no matter how it is displayed (formatted). However, if data is text, Excel will sort it as text.